# Firefox Profile cannot be loaded

Tags: firefox, user-profile

I am new to Ubuntu. Through dual boot (Windows 10 is the other OS), I am getting into Ubuntu. 
   Whenever I tried to open Firefox, I am getting the following error:

```
Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.
```

I uninstalled and installed Firefox once again. But I am getting same error.

I saw there is no profile folder in `.mozilla/firefox/<myprofilefolder>`

So, I tried to create the profile folder through command line by opening Profile manager:

`firefox -P` and `firefox -ProfileManager`

I am getting the following error.

```
Error: Access was denied while trying to open files in your profile directory.
```

So I gave the permission to the entire folder to create , read and delete for my name , group and others too. For sub-folders too.

Still I am unable to open the Firefox.

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: "So I gave the permission to the entire folder to create , read and delete for myname , group and others too. For subfolders too." You should have asked your question before doing this. Did you install FF using "purge"? If not you should have. What you should have done is remove the profile file and have FF make a new one. But changing  the permissions might have made this option impossible until you restore that.

Comment: @Rinzwind I uninstalled firefox using USC , using USC I installed firefox. I never tried purge. I will try purge and update the question. Thanks.

Comment: Purge remove user files and does not re-install it. Your problem is with a user file so ...

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me.

1.Kill all currently running process

```
killall firefox
killall thunderbird
```

2.Remove the cache Files

```
Note: Backup before removing.

$ rm -rf ~/.mozilla/
$ rm -rf ~/.cache/mozilla/
```

3.Change the ownership of following folders

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cache/.mozilla/
$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.mozilla/
```

** if the above step NOT successful, Then try following **

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache/.mozilla/
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.mozilla/
```

** if the above step NOT successful, Then try following **

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.cache/.mozilla/
$ sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.mozilla/
```

4.If all above steps NOT successful, Then change entire cache folder permission

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cache
```

or

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache
```

or

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.cache/
```