# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS - Firefox 80.0.1 error "Profile Missing" - "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. it may be missing or inaccessible"

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, firefox

I'm getting an error when trying to open firefox browser on my Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

I've already tried these three posts

- [Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022501/your-firefox-profile-cannot-be-loaded-it-may-be-missing-or-inaccessible)
- [Firefox Profile cannot be loaded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802183/firefox-profile-cannot-be-loaded)
- [Firefox profile cannot be loaded after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302891/firefox-profile-cannot-be-loaded-after-upgrade)

I followed all of the instructions.

I also tried uninstalling firefox and re-installing it.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Click the Places menu  and select Home Folder.

A File Browser window will appear.

Click the View menu and select Show Hidden Files if it isn't already checked.

Double click the folder marked .mozilla.

Double click the folder marked firefox.

Delete the profiles.ini file.

When you start Firefox, a new profile will be created.

Comment: hi and first, thanks for your answer,  i dont understand where is the Places menu is. can you please add a screenshot to describe that  ?

Comment: @jhoncli: I use XFCE. Look in your home directory, with the file manager, turn on view hidden files.

Comment: hi there im in the home file clicking the Show Hidden Files button, but nothing happend, its look like the folder is empty, it is also look like the folder empty when using the ls -a command on terminal.

Comment: @johncli: try this in a terminal: sudo apt update  --- sudo apt remove --purge firefox* --- sudo apt install firefox

Comment: hi there thank you for your help. i have solved the problem by uninstalling ubuntu on the Virtual Box and then Re-install it, i think the problem was that i deleted or moved my user home file by a mistake, and thats why the first solution did not worked up.